# FSharp GetGenericArguments().[0].Name returns T instead of actual type name

Tags: f#, system.reflection

I'm having an issue trying to reflect over a generic argument in F#.  I want to pass two types to a function: the first is the type I want to find implemented in another type (which is the 2nd parameter).

When I do this in C# I get the desired results.  However when I do it in F# I get Type.Name = "T" instead of "SomeType".  I have put together a Gist that hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do (it's just a linqpad sample to show what I'm trying to do) in both C# and F#: https://gist.github.com/johnbfair/11263203

Why is the result of .GetGenericArguments.[0].Name = "T" instead of "MySample2" (which is what C# outputs)?

Comment: Could you cut your example down to the minimum that shows the differences and put it inline here? Otherwise there's quite a lot to dig through.

Comment: If I try your F# code sample in F# Interactive, the result of invoking `typeImplements typeof<MySample2> typeof<MySample1<MySample2>>` is `true`. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes that's because I fixed the gist (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was making the mistake of using "typedefof<>" instead of "typeof<>".  Updated the gist accordingly.

To expand on the above:

When calling the function "typeImplements" I was passing in typedefof>. Unbeknownst to me typedefof doesn't include the type of the generic ('T) when interrogating the enclosing type (in this case MySample2).  So if you want to get the actual type of the generic you need to use typeof>.  This is the blog post that explained the difference to me: http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2013/05/difference-between-typeof-and-typedefof.html

Before:
`typeImplements typedefof<MySample2> typedefof<MySample1<MySample2>> |> Dump`
After: `typeImplements typeof<MySample2> typeof<MySample1<MySample2>> |> Dump`

Comment: Could you include a short summary of the correct solution in the answer here? (Just to keep the answer directly on the StackOverflow page.)